# Deep copy of binary tree

Tags: c++, c++11, binary-tree, deep-copy

I have this tree with different types of nodes that I need to do a deep copy on. The hierarchy looks something like this:

```
class AllNodes
{
    //this is a purely virtual base class
};
class TreeNode : public AllNodes
{
    AllNodes *rChild, *lChild;
};
class LeefNode : public AllNodes
{
    int value;
};
```

The problem is that when I want to do a deep copy of the entire tree, I don't know what nodes will have children and what nodes will have values. I've tried this, but it wont work (for obvious reasons):

```
void AllNodes::deepCopy(AllNodes* &copied, AllNodes* o)
{
    if(o->rChild == nullptr)
        copied->rChild = nullptr;
    else
    {
        copied->rChild = o->rChild;   
        deepCopy(copied->rchild, o->rChild);
    }

    if(o->lChild == nullptr)
        copied->lChild = nullptr;
    else
    {
        copied->lChild = o->lChild;
        deepCopy(copied->lChild, o->lChild);
    }
}
```

Does anyone have some ideas of how to accomplish this?

Comment: Hope that's really `AllNodes *rChild, *lChild;`. *Big* difference. And this makes no *node* copy *at all* If you're making a true deep "copy" you can expect to actually allocate some *nodes* in the process.

Comment: What if you simply used `value_ptr` to store the nodes? And `variant` to store either value or children.

Comment: You are just assigning the pointers so off course this is a shallow copy... allocate the memory first and then copy the data into that new memory and then assign the pointers

Comment: @WhozCraig Yeah, that was a typo. Yes, I know that my deepCopy method doesn't do anything constructive, just thought I'd share my progress.

Comment: @JohanHjalmarsson a little different than most binary tree copies. So your mid-nodes don't have any data?, only the leaf nodes do? How do you decide which direction to traverse the mid-nodes to reach the eventual object of a desired search?

Comment: @WhozCraig exactly I was thinking the samething ... form the question it exactly looks like your are interpreting it ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a virtual method and implement it in TreeNode and LeafNode.

```
class AllNodes
{
    //this is a purely virtual base class
    virtual AllNodes* copy() const = 0;
};
class TreeNode : public AllNodes
{
    AllNodes* rChild, lChild;
    virtual AllNodes* copy() const {
         TreeNode *n = new TreeNode;
         n->rChild = rChild->copy();
         n->lChild = lChild->copy();
         return n;
    }
};
class LeafNode : public AllNodes
{
    int value;
    virtual AllNodes* copy() const {
         LeafNode *n = new LeafNode;
         n->value = value;
         return n;
    }
};
```

(Just a draft)

Comment: Neat! I'll try it out.

Answer (score 2):

This is polymorphic behavior (creating a deep copy, based on the concrete type of the object). As such, it should be implemented in a virtual function, accross the entire nodes hierarchy.

The function to perform the deep copy is usually called clone:

```
class AllNodes
{
    //this is a purely virtual base class
public:
    virtual AllNodes* clone() = 0;
};

class TreeNode : public AllNodes
{
    AllNodes *rChild, *lChild; // you skipped declaring lChild as a pointer
public:
    virtual AllNodes* clone() override // recursive implementation for child nodes
    {
         return new TreeNode{
             rChild ? rChild->clone() : nullptr,
             lChild ? lChild->clone() : nullptr }; // assume existence of this
                                                   // constructor
    }
};

class LeafNode : public AllNodes
{
    int value;
public:
    virtual AllNodes* clone() override
    {
        return new LeafNode{ value }; // assume existence of this constructor
    }
};
```

Client code (deep copy of the entire tree):

```
AllNodes *original; // filled in elsewhere
AllNodes *deepCopy = original->clone();
```